# SeoBundle - title and description are not set

Tags: symfony, seo, sonata, symfony-cmf

I have configured `SeoBundle` as stated in [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/seo/introduction.html):

```
sonata_seo:
    page:
        title: Default title
        metas:
            name:
                description: Defualt description
                keywords: key1, key2

cmf_seo:
    title: seo.title
    description: seo.description
    content_listener:
        enabled: false
```

And placed in `base.html.twig`:

```
<head>
    {# meta #}
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>

    {{ sonata_seo_title() }}

    {{ sonata_seo_metadatas() }}

    ...
</head>
```

Now when I refresh page I can see that `sonata_seo` block title and description are set instead of `cmf_seo`. In docs there is a warning:

> The title and description template is only used when the title is not
>   set on the content object or when the content object is not available,
>   otherwise it'll use the default set by the SonataSeoBundle. You should
>   make sure that the defaults also follow the template.

If only docs would clarify what is "content object" would be great... Anyway I tried removing title and description from `sonata_seo` block:

```
sonata_seo:
    page: ~

cmf_seo:
    title: seo.title
    description: seo.description
    content_listener:
        enabled: false
```

Now my title becomes "Sonata Project" which is default `SonataSeoBundle` title.

How do I display `cmf_seo` title? `{{ cmf_seo_title() }}` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

what is the value of `seo.title` and `seo.description` is it something you expect to be translated? Can you serve a longer stacktrace for the exception please?

In general `CmfSeoBundle` expects some placeholders (`%%content_description%%`, `%%content_title%%`, doubled to make it translatable at the end) to enrich the title/description with dynamic data. That dynamic data can live as `SeoContent` on the document (content object) you are persisting or as so called extractors which fetch the data from the document (content object). In the first case you have to implement `SeoAwareInterface` in second case you can find several extractors in the [doucmentation[(https://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/seo/extractors.html).

If you wanna simply set static titles, you should stay with the `SonataSeoBundle`. We do simply enrich a template defined in `cmf_seo.title|description` with dynamic data from the current content. We do need `sonata_seo.title` for pages with no content documents (i.e. static pages).

Comment: Please give me some feedback if we simply have to improve our docs, or have to fix some code or if you try to tell me a hidden feature request :-)